# How to authenticate spring boot endpoint programmatically?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Spring Boot application, I enable one endpoint i.e. `metrics` endpoint. At same moment I don't want to make it public so I configured it with the following setting:

```
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=ENC(l2y+PuJeGIOMshbv+ddZgK8lOe2TRdt9YIuMwB5g5Ws=)
security.basic.enabled=false

management.context-path=/manager
management.port=8082
management.address=127.0.0.2
management.security.enabled=false
management.security.roles=SUPERUSER
management.ssl.enabled=true
management.ssl.key-store=file:keystore.jks
management.ssl.key-password=ENC(l2y+PuJeGIOMshbv+ddZgK8lOe2TRdt9YIuMwB5g5Ws=)

endpoints.metrics.id=metrics
endpoints.metrics.sensitive=true
endpoints.metrics.enabled=true
```

Basically, if someone trying to access `https://127.0.0.2:8082/manager/metrics` URI throw any browser then he/she needs to supply a username (`security.user.name=admin`) and password (`security.user.password=ENC(l2y+PuJeGIOMshbv+ddZgK8lOe2TRdt9YIuMwB5g5Ws=)`) in a popup.

Now I have java client which is running on the same machine(in future it may run in a remote location) but with a different host and port i.e. `127.0.0.1:8081` trying to access the above URI programmatically, but unable to do so and end up with response code 401.

401 is the response code for UNAUTHORISED access which is obvious. My query is **is it possible to supply username and password programmatically to access the above URI i.e. `https://127.0.0.2:8082/manager/metrics`? or firewall is the only way to secure it?**.

My java client code:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","D://SpringBoot/SpringWebAngularJS/truststore.ts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","p@ssw0rd");
    try {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){
            public boolean verify(String hostname,SSLSession sslSession) {
                return hostname.equals("127.0.0.2");
            }
        });
        URL obj = new URL("https://127.0.0.2:8082/manager/metrics");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.err.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode); //Response code 401
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the described behavior of the browser, i assume that the endpoint is secured by basic authentication.

Basic authentication expects an "Authorization" Header containing the username and password in the following form encoded in base64: "username:password"

If you use java 8 you can use the base64 encoder provided in the java util package as follows:

```
import java.util.Base64;

con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", Base64.getEncoder().encode("yourUsername:yourPassword".getBytes());
```

Just to provide a little further information:

This is the exact same thing your browser does. It sends the request and gets a 401 Response containing a header `WWW-Authenticate: Basic`. So the browser knows that the authentication method is basic auth and asks you to provide your username and password which then will be encoded by base64 and added to the authorization header when the browser performs the same request a second time.

Comment: glad it helped. I just provided a little further information. There is not authentication mechanism that you can't do programmatically since every browser is a program itself. It's just about to find out which authentication mechanism is used and then sending the request in the right form :)